# What are the strongest combinations of Pantheon Spirits for AFK?

Tags: cookie-clicker

In Cookie Clicker, there is a Pantheon that lets you slot Spirits to get bonuses. I would like to know which Spirits are best for an AFK/low attention build and where they should be slotted.

Right now, I have Mokalsium (milk power up) in Diamond, Skruuia (wrinkler power up) in Ruby, and Holobore (base CPS up) in Jade. I assume these three are the best for AFK builds, but I do not know if their slotting is as optimal as it could be, which is what led me to asking this question.

As for my run, I am currently in what I assume to be the end game. I have 377/439 for achievements and my current CPS (without wrinklers) is 221.526 undecillion.

Comment: Coule you add info on your overall number of achievements and CPS ? The answer depends on these info.

Comment: @Fana I can do that, though wouldn't there be thresholds? Like if Number of Achievements is X or greater, this combination is best, while if not and CPS is greater than Y, this other combination is better. Just so other people trying to use this question and answer to help optimize their Pantheon can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have Mokalsium in the right place (milk is op), but you should move Holobre to Ruby and put Jeremy in Jade, since their CPS increase is actually quite substantial. Using Skruuia is a common mistake, because while its description says that Wrinklers consume more cookies, they actually just return more when popped, so right before you pop your wrinklers, slot Skruuia in Diamond, pop them, and then unslot them again. If you want to farm sugar lumps though, I'd replace Holobre or Jeremy with Rigidel. (Side note- Rigidel's effect is only active while the game is open.)

Answer (score -3):

For AFK farming you want to use the following three spirits
Jeremy- spirit of industry
Cyclus- spirit of ages
Holobore-spirit of asceticism

Comment: Is there a reason why I should use those three in particular? Is it mathematically better than the three I mentioned? Also, when using Cyclus, he does practically nothing if you are AFK (he gives CPS during his up time but removes CPS during his down time, making it even out at a net gain of 0 unless you are slotting and removing him throughout the day).

Comment: I can somewhat understand the other spirits, but why Cyclus, he legit does nothing for afk setups